# Aplying permutations to transform expressions

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Take $n = 3$ and let $x_1, x_2, x_3$ be three variables. Let an element in S3 act as a function. Example: $(132)$ sends  $x_1 →  x_3, x_2 →  x_1, x_3 → x_2$.
>
> Now define an expression $Δ  =  (x_1 – x_2)(x_1 – x_3)(x_2 – x_3)$. Let $j = (123)$, then $j(Δ) = (x_2 – x_3)(x_2 – x_1)(x_3 – x_1)$.
>
> Notice that this is just the expression for $Δ$ with two of the brackets, $(x_1−x_2)$ and $(x_1−x_3)$, reversed. So $(123)$ sends $Δ → Δ$.

Questions:

1. How did we get $j(Δ)$? We know that $(123)$ sends  $x_1 →  x_2, x_2 →  x_3, x_3 → x_1$, but can we use the given rule to transform elements in $(x_1 – x_2)$ separately instead of applying $(123)$ to the whole expression $(x_1 – x_2)$? If so, why?
2. I don't get how $(x_1 – x_2)(x_1 – x_3)(x_2 – x_3)$ and  $(x_2 – x_3)(x_2 – x_1)(x_3 – x_1)$ are the same expression. Please, elaborate on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening for your first question is that $j$ is being extended by linearity and products.

We know that $j(x_1)=x_2$, $j(x_2)=x_3$, and $j(x_3)=x_1$.  Now, what would be $j(x_1-x_2)$?  We actually don't know what it would be (it could be anything).  However, in algebra, we like functions that preserve operations (homomorphisms).  So, the most natural thing to do is $j(x_1-x_2)=j(x_1)-j(x_2)$.

Similarly, when we want to deal with $j((x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_3))$, we haven't defined what this should be, but the definition that preserves the multiplication is $j(x_1-x_2)j(x_1-x_3)$.

So, we can compute
$$
j(\Delta)=j(x_1-x_2)j(x_1-x_3)j(x_2-x_3)=(i(x_1)-j(x_2))(j(x_1)-j(x_3))(j(x_2)-j(x_3)).
$$

For your second question, factor $(-1)$ from $(x_2-x_1)$ and from $(x_3-x_1)$.  Then, rearrange the factors.

Comment: @ Michael Burr, Fabulous.